# Rules for articles usage

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any simple rules for article usage (“a” vs “the” vs none)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none)

Is there a good rule for articles usage? I just don't get it and everytime in doubts.