# Do I need to use 'the' in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

> I would like to limit  my dissertation to three spheres: economy, politics, and culture of America.

Do I need to add 'the' before economy, politics...?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none

Comment: There should be no whitespace before the colon. This is English, not French.

Comment: I think it would be decidedly odd to say *"I'm talking about economy of America"* or *"...American economy"*, so I don't think the word *"the"* can be discarded in the context of this list, even though it's possible to discard it with *politics* and *culture*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with *the economy, politics and culture*.

The reason I prefer that is because there are two senses of economy.

> 1. the state of a country or region in terms of the production and consumption of goods and services and the supply of money
> 2. careful management of available resources

The second is a *mass noun* so using the definite article precludes it.  Of course, the reader should infer meaning number 1 anyway but I think it sounds better this way.

Comment: I was tempted to say that he would be better to write, "economics, politics, and culture" etc, to get the parallelism between "economics" and "politics". But I thought a little more and concluded it didn't matter. Debateable, I guess.

Comment: @Jay Yes was tempted to say that too!  But for some reason it sounds better this way. I was also tempted to post a lot of examples like "It's *the economy*, stupid" and "a day in politics is a long time" but I can't really explain in more detail precisely why you do need the article for *the economy*.  I agree with the comment on the related question I posted that it's something you have to just get a feel for in English rather than something governed by set rules.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between ***economy*** and ***the economy*** here (so it is with the rest.)

> I would like to limit my dissertation to three spheres: economy, politics, and culture of America.

refers to the academic subjects.

> I would like to limit my dissertation to three spheres: the economy, the politics, and the culture of America.

refers to the state of these things at some of time, presumed current, unless defined in context.

That's the way I would understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that sentence would be grammatically correct with no "the", with a single "the" before "economy", or with a "the" before each of the three items. My inclination would be to include three "the"s, but I don't think it's wrong without it, nor do I see how it would change the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As it is something listing it seems you do not need using "the".
This may be another alternative:

> I would like to limit my dissertation to three spheres: American economy, American politics, and American culture.