# "The messenger" vs "A messenger"

Tags: articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Are there any simple rules for article usage (“a” vs “the” vs none)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none)

Can someone explain the difference between 'the messenger' and 'a messenger'? Please don't just explain that one is a definite and another is an indefinite article. I have seen people using both where differentiating one from the other seems difficult to understand. For example:

> I am just the messenger.
>
> I am just a messenger.

Comment: But it really is just the difference between a definite article and an indefinite one. The same difference in meaning that applies for any "an/the" case applies here.

Comment: Then, I think I am just overly reacting.

Comment: a messenger: any messenger. The messenger: the only messenger, or the only important one worth considering (usually referring to a message just delivered). However, this shading of meaning is not dependant on "messenger", just on the context in which you might have a unique or important messenger that can be "the" messenger. The same context-sensitive differences apply whenever you have an "a/an vs the" situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The messenger* appears to be used when there is a specific message that is the topic of conversation. I.e. *I am just the messenger (who brought the message)*. On the other hand, *a messenger* does not necessarily imply that that you are discussing a specific messages, but rather any messages from some source.