# "Everyone knows what a/the proton is"

Tags: pronouns, articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any simple rules for article usage (“a” vs “the” vs none)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none)

Which is correct?

1. Everyone knows what a proton is.
2. Everyone knows what the proton is.
3. Everyone knows what proton is.

Answer (score 7):

> Everyone knows what a proton is.

This is the most-used construct.

> Everyone knows what the proton is.

This structure is a bit old-fashioned for general use, but is commonplace in [scientific contexts](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=proton-shrinks-in-size).

> Everyone knows what proton is.

This is ungrammatical.  A correct way to say it is *everyone knows what protons are*.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 seems to emphasize "proton" as an ontological value.
Option 3 sounds more abstract than 1, in the sense that "proton" could be a quality and not a noun, as in the case of "a proton".
I'd say that being right or wrong depends on what you are writing. Withouth the specific context, any of them could be right.