# "In a book store near my school" vs. "in the book store near my school"

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any simple rules for article usage (“a” vs “the” vs none)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none)

Which article should I use in the following situations?

1. There is only one book store near my school, and I buy books there. Suppose that I'm having a conversation with a person who doesn't know anything about that book store, my school, how many book stores are near it, or if there are any at all. Which of the following should I use?

   > - I buy books in *a* book store near my school.
   > - I buy books in *the* book store near my school.
2. The same situation, but there are several book stores near my school, and I buy books in only one of them.
3. The same situation, but I buy books in all of the book stores without any distinction.

I hope that I made myself clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

1. I buy books in the book store near my school OR I buy books in a book store near my school.
2. I buy books in a book store near my school.
3. I buy books in the book stores near my school.

Comment: You could also leave the article out of the third one.

Comment: seeing no much of difference o.o +1