# Correct placement of articles

Tags: articles

My supervisor corrected the draft of my thesis, inserting a lot of articles here and there. I have doubts if he was correct. Could someone comment on the following sentences?

> Over the last decade a lot of companies recognized [the] importance of
>   data warehousing     and business intelligence technologies to their
>   businesses. Complex queries can significantly decrease [the]
>   performance of a source system. [The] Availability and quality of data
>   is crucial for this process. Because of [the] standardization of SQL,
>   [the] technical heterogeneity could be solved automatically.

Comment: All of these are required for ordinary idiomatic English.

Comment: Thankk you. I always have problems with articles. Is there a nice, easy to remember set of rules? I know the basic rules, like when we talk about something particular, we put "the". But, in my opinion, "importance of data warehousing" is quite general term, that's why I omit the article.

Comment: Actually, @damluar, that "the" makes sense but the "the" added to "(The) Availability and quality of data..." seems unecessary.

Comment: @ColinFine, could you please explain why we need "the" in "decrease the performance"? Isn't it a general performance?

Comment: I would say the _the_ before _performance_ is optional. I would add it (as you talk about the performance of a specific system), but it still works without (as you could mean any system, not a particular one).

Comment: I think if you had written "decrease performance of source systems" then you'd be right but like Oliver stated, you are addressing a particular source system the way it is written.

Comment: @ColinFine I might omit the very last one.

Comment: @damluar Your question might be a better fit for [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange site](http://ell.stackexchange.com) than here.

Comment: I agree with ColinFine, Kristina, and tchrist: all the additions are good, but the third (“[The] Availability and quality of data”) and the fifth (“[the] technical heterogeneity”) could go either way.  But I believe everybody missed another problem: I would say “The availability and quality of data ***are*** crucial …”).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with all the corrections, but it could be argued that not all of them are strictly necessary for it to be grammatically correct. In "[the] importance of data warehousing" it is definitely necessary. In "[the] standardization of SQL" it should be there, but could conceivably be left out, giving it a more generic sense. But on the whole I would leave them all in and agree with your supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that almost all cases where your supervisor added "the" involve constructions with "of". I've been told you'd most often use "the" in such phrases ("the X of Y"), e.g.: the joy of singing, the limitations of the web, the content of this website, the initiatives of NGOs, etc. I've stuck to this rule for quite a long time now and I don't think I've ever been corrected.