# usage of articles: definite article or zero article?

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

> - the Chinese invented the paper
> - the Chinese invented paper

I can't decide which article we get before *paper* — zero article or *the*.

Are we talking about paper in general (so zero article is used before it) or is the definite article *the* used?

Comment: The answers at [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) answer this.

Comment: i can't understand which answer we get here from(are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite) so could you answer my question,plase

Comment: [Answer about definite/indefinite article](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2033/18696) | [Answer about zero article](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/9288/18696)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it may be asked on ELL. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about paper in general you never use either the definite nor the indefinite article. You would only use 'the' if you were speaking of some specific paper. e.g. 'The paper in the photocopier is getting low'.

Comment: this is the sentense i have got in my English exam the teachers say it should be zero article because they are talking about paper in general but,we-in the exam-can't decide if they are talking in general or for a specific paper.As a result i just wanna have the best answer

Comment: @Kathrine. If you mean the sentence in your OP, the correct version is 'The Chinese invented paper.' There are several errors, however, in your comment above. You need to write in sentences with full stops and capital letters. The word 'I', is always capitalised. And there is no such word as 'wanna'. I think you mean 'want to'.