# Using "the/a/an" with "and" and "or"

Tags: articles, conjunctions, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Suppose I need to mention two nouns in a phrase so that they are joined with either "and" or "or". Do I use "the/a/an" with the both of the nouns or just with the first one?

Comment: This depends entirely on context. There is no hard-and-fast "rule" about articles with conjunctions. It's quite likely that [our existing question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none) will answer this one, but nobody can tell without the sentence you're asking about.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'm looking for an explanation that would address this in general. And I couldn't find any explanations on the page of the question you refer to.

Comment: [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This question does depend entirely on context, so for the moment I'm voting for that duplicate. Please edit the question with full details of what you're asking about, and then it can be re-opened if there is enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still dependent on the nouns you use whether singular or plural (except "the"), count or non-count.  The definite article "the" is used for all genders in singular or plural. "a" is used for singular count nouns that start with consonant sounds and "an' for singular count nouns that start with vowel sounds.

Check this out http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/artikel.htm
http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/artikel2.htm