# Use of articles "the"/"a"

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles

> - I went to *the* market and then I went to *the* Cafe.
> - I went to *a* market and then I went *a* cafe

In the above sentences, what is the difference in nuance between them *a* market/*a* Cafe, and *the* market/*the* cafe?

My friend said "the market" has two meanings. One meaning is "shopping" and the other is the market *building*. Is it correct?

The other,  "a market" is just a market building. It means I went there for shopping or to meet someone etc. So, I just go to a building. Is it correct?

Is it the same with "I went to *the* Cafe or I went to *a* Cafe"?

Generally when you speak a stranger using words like "a market/cafe" or "the market/cafe" for the first time, from who's point of view do you speak, you or the stranger? Which article is appropriate, "a" or "the"?

Comment: Is your question answered by [this one about definite/indefinite articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)? If it isn't, please [edit your question](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/202545/edit) to say what you still need to know. This is a duplicate candidate.

Comment: Please also proofread your post before submitting. There is no such thing as "grammer" or "sentance", there must be no white space before a question mark, etc. Thank you.