# Which article is used between a "name" and a "tagline"

Tags: grammar, articles, names

Suppose, I am selling a new product named as: "Innob" and there is a tagline followed by it: "___, new breath in (the) town".

Which article shall I use between the name and the tagline ("the" vs "a/an")?
In other words, which is grammatically correct between below 2:

> "Innob, **the** new breath in (the) town"

OR

> "Innob, **a** new breath in (the) town"

[Note: tagline is altered for privacy, however the question remains the same]

Comment: Intrigued by what you mean by 'breath', which is not usually something which can be new or old. Perhaps this is a mistranslation and a different word might be better?

Comment: @Mynamite, just a random word selected. You may put anything instead of *breath*; e.g. *"new sensation in the software world"*

Comment: related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Reference- oxforddictionaries.com*

**the new**- *[Produced, introduced, or discovered recently or now for the first time; not existing before:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/new)*

> "Innob, **[the](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/new)** new breath in (**the**) town.

**a new-** *Already existing but seen, experienced, or acquired recently or now for the first time*.

> "Innob, **[a](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/new)** new breath in (**the**) town.

I proffer:

> "Innob, **the** new breath in **your** town.

[References:](http://www.gktoday.in/list-of-punch-lines-of-famous-companies-brands-banks-movies-tourism-places-etc/)

•Tourism: *The* Perfect Host

•Mcdowells Signature: *The* New Sign Of Success

•Sun Microsystems: The Network Is *The* Computer

Comment: I know both are correct; But which is better?

Comment: @iammilind *Better* is a matter of opinion, and unanswerable on this site.

Answer (score 1):

*Grammatically* both are correct, but the meaning is different:

- "**a** new ..." refers to one out of many, whereas
- "**the** new ..." refers to one specific thing, in this case your product which is (hopefully) unique and therefore attractive for customers.

=> for advertising purposes, I'd choose "the new xyz".

Comment: The link you posted actually implies that I should use article *"a"* instead of *"the"*. Because the person seeing this may not know about the product and hence it is more suitable with *"a"*. What do you suggest?

Comment: NO, because you want to emphazise the uniqueness of your product. You dont want to imply it's *just one of many*, a indistinct one. Basically, you are doing it backwards: using "the" implies that the person reading the advert should know this product.