# Is it correct to say "a new" or "the new"?

Tags: adjectives, articles

That's the whole question.
Example:

> I'm creating a new version of the program

Is there a set of rules one should follow?
Thank you!

Comment: That depends what you want to say. For example: "I am (the person which is) creating (specifically) the new version of the program. " or "(No, I am not just bug fixing,) I am creating a (whole) new version of the program."

Comment: Yes it is correct to say "a new" or "the new".

Comment: @MarvMills was that supposed to be funny? BTW, you're missing a comma after "Yes".

Comment: Only if you consider my use of "Yes" to be an interjection, which it is not. See here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78532/comma-or-semicolon-after-no-when-responding-to-a-question

Comment: The link you provided only proved my point. You're missing something, let's say it like that :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which article is used between a "name" and a "tagline"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220996/which-article-is-used-between-a-name-and-a-tagline)

Comment: It's pretty unreasonable to close this as off-topic in an English language forum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Context, context, context!

The basic rule is that you use *the* if you expect your hearers/readers to know which one you're talking about.

So if you've already mentioned this new version, or it's part of the general knowledge you share with your hearers/readers, you can use *the*. But when you introduce a new entity into the discourse, you use *a*.

> I know the program's slow right now, but I'm writing ***a*** new version. ***The*** new version will be released in May.

You may also use *the* to speak of a new entity ***if*** you distinguish it immediately, within the same noun phrase.

> We're working on three new versions. ***The*** version ***I am working on*** is targeted to social media users.

Answer (score 2):

The use of the definite or indefinite article depends on the meaning you would like to express. Both cases are  possible in different situations.

*a new version* is the case of the noun modified with the descriptive adjective, therefore, the indefinite article can be chosen.

*the new version* -you are telling the reader which thing we are talking about. You are referring to the particular version of the program.

Comment: Thank you for such **the** quick response. Just kidding :)