# Is the definite article "the" needed in "from illness"?

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

Is it absolutely necessary to use "the" or "his"before the word "illness" in the following sentence to make it correct?

> Last winter Victor got such a serious infection that it took him two months to recover from illness.

Comment: We have a "canonical question" for this sort of query: [Simple rules for articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a). Adding an article changes the nature of the word *illness* here.

Comment: @Andrew: I agree that a determiner (*the* or *his*) changes the nature of the word *illness*, but I don't see any reasonable justification for leaving a determiner out in this sentence. Victor is not recovering from *generic* illness, which is what I think a lack of determiner would imply.

Comment: So the sentece without "the" or "his" is gramatically correct?

Comment: Both are **grammatically** correct (as the linked question shows). But the word *illness* changes slightly depending on whether the article is present or not.

Comment: Could you please specify how 'the illness' differs from 'illness' in that particular sentence. Thank you.

Comment: I think *illness* without an article tends to mean a generic illness, so you could use it in the sentence *"Victor always takes a long time to recover from illness"*. However, what you're talking about in your sentence is a specific illness (the one he got last winter), so *his illness* or *the illness* would be more appropriate. But *illness* without an article is not definitively wrong here; when you ask *"is it absolutely necessary"*, I think the answer has to be *"no"*.

Comment: Cambridge Learner's dictionary: **illness** (countable) a disease of the body or mind; **illness** (uncountable) the state of being ill. And *the illness* is the countable meaning, while *illness* is the uncountable meaning.

Answer (score 0):

So according to Mr. Andrew Leach and Mr. Peter Shor in the comments, **both sentences are grammatically correct**. However, the word **illness**'s meaning will slightly change depending on whether the article is present or not. The lack of a determiner would mean Victor is recovering from **generic illness**, whileas the presence of a determiner would mean that Victor is recovering from a **specific illness** (the illness that both parties, the speaker and the listener, know about).

Credit to: **Andrew Leach** & **Peter Shor** who answered this in the comments.
I only compiled their answers. This question has long been answered. It shouldn't have been under the "Unanswered" section for this long.

Answer (score 0):

**The** is anaphoric. Without **the** the noun becomes generic.

Comment: Well, "anaphoric" is not the term I'd use, though it does become generic without the article. I think one is better off not trying to define, delimit, explain, or otherwise predict anything about _the_, except noting when it's used.