# demanded by or demanded for

Tags: prepositions, collocation

I doubt about the correct preposition here.

Which sentence should I use if it is the engineers themselves who are clamouring for the equipment?

> This instrument is highly **demanded** **for** engineers
>
> This instrument is highly **demanded** **by** engineers

or are both correct?

and how about this?

> It is highly demanded instrument **for** engineers
>
> It is highly demanded instrument **by** engineers

Comment: Are the engineers doing the demanding? Or someone else? Preposition questions [must state the intended meaning](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/prepositions/info) as it's the meaning which determines the correct preposition to obtain that sense.

Comment: If you mean engineers are demanding it, then *by*. If you mean it's being demanded on behalf of engineers (by other people), then *for*. For a more detailed explanation, please ask on our sister site for those baffled by the mischievous imps of the English language, prepositions: [ELL.se].

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes I mean engineers demand it. thanks

Comment: @AndrewLeach, could you help  me with the second added part too?

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highly+demanded%2Cin+great+demand&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chighly%20demanded%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20great%20demand%3B%2Cc0) show that 'in great demand' is vastly more common than 'highly demanded'.

Comment: In the second set of sentences, it should be _it is **a** highly demanded instrument_.

Comment: If the meaning is the same, then the preposition is the same. However: [there is a question about articles](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) which is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

For the situation when the engineers themselves demand the instrument, you definitely use

> This instrument is highly demanded by engineers.

You can come up with the preposition (by or for) by attributing the action of demanding:

- engineers demand = **demanded by engineers**
- someone else demands = **demanded for engineers** (by someone else).

In the second case there is a third party as the source of the action.

As to your second question, the concept is the same plus in case of 'for', the meaning is dual:

1. demanded for the engineers' work process
2. demanded for engineers by someone else

Remember to use 'a' article with 'is'

> It is **a** highly demanded instrument ...

Answer (score 0):

Considers these examples:

*This instrument is highly demanded **for engineers** by **management**.*

for engineers: **for the benefit of** engineers, the management is placing /orders/requests/ for it, or buys it, so the engineers could use its superior functionality, etc.

*This instrument is highly demanded **by engineers**, who are asking for it every day.*

by engineers: the **engineers themselves are asking for it**

Answer (score 0):

demanded by = someone else ask for that thing
Example:Salary hike is **demanded by** the employee
Here the salary is asked by the employee

demanded for = Something is **asked for** the other person
Example:The Team Leader **demanded for** the salary hike of team members.