# Definite/Indefinite articles: "first mention" vs "specific object"

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Rules say

> Use A(AN) when talking about a thing which is new, unknown, or introduced to a listener for the first time.

At the same time, they say

> The definite article is used when the speaker talks about a specific object.

Now let's look at the following sentence. This is a commit message for the version control system I'm trying to write correctly:

`Added a/the/Ø prototype for a/the/Ø bar() function`

On the one hand, I mention this function and its prototype for the first time, but on the other hand, I talk about specific objects. So which articles should I use?

Comment: You could say  "*the prototype*" or "*a prototype*", depending on whether it is expected to be the only prototype *for that function*, or whether you or others may write a second or additional prototypes for that function.  Assuming the "bar function" is a specific one, you need *the*.

Comment: I don't know where your "Rules" came from: altho' they may be helpful guidance, I don't consider them definitive.  Certainly "the" refers to a specific single item, and "a" refers to one or more items of the same type.  But I wouldn't say that "new, unknown, or introduced to a listener for the first time" necessarily require the indefinite article - it depends what you're referring to.

Comment: The second guideline takes priority over the first. The first guideline is for sentences like "A cat sat on the mat.", where the *cat* isn't sufficiently specified to use *the*. In the *prototype* example, use whichever combination of articles communicates your intent about the *uniqueness* of the prototype and of the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Answer (score 2):

It's more complex than you may suspect.
Specificity is different from definiteness, and must be distinguished from it.

An indefinite article can mark either a non-specific, descriptive NP, as in

- *I'm looking for **a policeman**, but I can't find **one**.*
  (*a policeman* here means 'anyone fitting the description of a policeman')

or it can mark a specific individual NP, as in

- *I'm looking for **a policeman**, but I can't find **him**.*
  (*a policeman* here means 'some individual policeman, who is known to me')

Furthermore, there's just no general rule for usage of English articles. Article grammar is a disorganized mass of idioms and specialized contexts, like *I dialed **the** wrong number*.

Comment: Please clarify what your initial "Not quite" refers to, especially bearing in mind that the order of answers & addition of comments can change the sequence of items.