# This book is the property of

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

I have hard time understanding why in this phrase, *property* is preceded with a definite article. As this book is one of many properties, the indefinite article sounds more natural, to me.

Of course, I'm wrong, but I would like to know why.

Comment: "Property" is not any other property, but the property modified (restricted) by the prepositional phrase that is headed by "of".

Comment: You wouldn't say, "This is *a* house where I live." (unless you have 2 or more homes!): you would say "This is *the* house where I live." because you are identifying that one particular house.  Likewise, you would say "This book is *my* property." or "This book is *the* property of Fred."

Comment: @TrevorD Not that I'm arguing but if I say "This book is one of my properties" wouldn't "This book is a property of mine" be the right alternative?

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that either of the previous answers truly nails the rationale behind this usage. I don't think the following does either, but I consider the reasoning a useful addition.

Both

> The bank has a responsibility to inform customers of changes in
>   interest rates.

and

> The bank has the responsibility to inform customers of changes in
>   interest rates.

are quite acceptable.

This argues that qualification of a noun is not the sole factor involved.

(Though these versions are near-interchangeable, the one with the definite article carries at least a hint that the need to inform people of interest-rate changes is common knowledge. And, although the version with the indefinite article may be said to carry a hint of other responsibilities, I'd say that this isn't a count-noun usage.)

Perhaps it's possible only to say that the definite article is often the default choice (or perhaps on occasion just **a** choice) with non-count nouns in expressions that have become idiomatic:

> [This accident was] the fault of ... [nobody in particular, say]
>
> the responsibility of
>
> the property of
>
> [Did they have] the chance of
>
> He had the nerve to ...

......

> felt a/the need to

... but note

> have a/n duty / obligation / mind to.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. The noun *responsibility* has both countable and non-countable usage. Also, I don't think my answer says "qualification of a noun is the sole factor involved". In which part of my answer did I imply that?

Comment: Your answer doesn't even mention countness, far less the grey area about whether 'has a responsibility to' shows a count, non-count, or somewhere-in-between usage (note that, although 'a' is used, 'has two responsibilities to' would sound most unnatural under most circumstances).

Comment: The OP didn't ask about countness and I don't think your example sentences "the bank has..." are relevant to the OP's question as the *to-infinitive* could be interpreted in both ways as adverbial and adjectival. I think that's where your confusion comes from.

Answer (score 3):

**The** question **on** whether to use a definite article or indefinite article is not easy to answer. (Please note I used "the" instead of "a" in this sentence).

In your example "This book is **the** property **of**...", "property" is not any other property, but the property modified (restricted) by the prepositional phrase that is headed by "of".

The following [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the) definition *2 b (1)* explins that "the" is

> used as a function word before a noun to **limit its application** to that
>   specified by a **succeeding element** in the sentence: '*the poet
>   Wordsworth*", '*the days of our youth*', '*didn't have the time to write*'

As you can see, **the** nouns in the three examples are all modified – by a proper noun *Wordsworth*, prepositional phrase *of our youth* and to infinitive *to write* respectively.

Related question: [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: But this fails to distinguish between 'This is the home of the Smiths' (quite possibly a unique designation) and 'This is the property of the Smiths' (as, no doubt, are a lot of other things). I believe the latter is a heavily idiomatic usage, and can't think offhand of similar examples.

Comment: Notice also that in 'I didn't have the time.' the noun isn't (overtly) qualified, but is certainly non-count.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer relates specifically to British English.]

**Property** (in the sense of *possessions*) is a non-count / uncountable / mass noun.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/property) define it as follows:

> A thing or things belonging to someone; possessions collectively
>   Examples:
>   *she wanted Oliver and his property out of her flat*
>   *the stolen property was not recovered*
>   *When arrests were made stolen property was recovered that belonged to two victims of a robbery in the town centre.*
>   *He also faces a charge of possessing stolen property in connection with the March 11 incident.*
>   *Police are recommending charges of possessing stolen property, and break, enter and theft against the man.*
>
> *Law* The right to the possession, use, or disposal of something; ownership:
>   Examples:
>   *rights of property*
>   *But how were those notions of ownership and property understood in customary terms?*
>   *Just because of the abuse of property ownership, private property should not altogether be eliminated.*
>   *The second major element in communist doctrine was the social ownership of property and central planning of the economy.*

[Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/property) define it as follows:

> an object or objects that belong to someone
>   Examples:
>   *The club does not accept responsibility for loss of or damage to club members' personal property.*
>   *Both books have "Government property" stamped inside them.*
>   *Children need to be taught to have respect for other people's property.*
>
> *specialized: law* the legal right to own and use something
>   *The new tax system would be calculated on the value of property owned by an individual.*
>   *Apparently he was sacked after he was caught stealing company property.*
>   *The police impounded cars and other personal property belonging to the drug dealers.*
>   *The fire resulted in damage to their property.*
>   *In an auction, goods or property are sold to the highest bidder.*

Because (in the senses mentioned above) ***property*** is a mass noun, it is not normally used with the indefinite article "**a**", nor in the plural form.

The expression quoted in the question: *This book is the property of ...* therefore uses "*the* property".
Likewise, one could say: "This book is *my* property."

For the same reasons, one could not say:
"This book is one of my properties" or "This book is a property of mine". The use of the word *property* in the plural, or as a singular count-noun with the indefinite article "a", in that way would immediately make one think of land or buildings, rather than possessions (for the reasons given in the next paragraph).

Note that, when used to refer to a building and/or land, ***property*** can be used either as a *mass noun* or as a *count noun*, and therefore can also be used in the plural form, or in the singular form with the indefinite article "a". (See the dictionary references cited above for further details.)

Additionally, when used to refer to "an attribute, quality, or characteristic of something", ***property*** is used as a *count noun*, and therefore can also be used in the plural form.  (See the dictionary references cited above for further details.)

Comment: Nouns appearing as mass nouns can be used with the indefinite article in some circumstances: _A golden light flooded the clearing_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. Have changed first para below definitions accordingly.

Comment: A less arguable example is [Formal / literary style]:
'The new trainee spoke at the staff meeting with an enormous enthusiasm.' 'Light' in the previous example may be perhaps be considered somewhere between count and non-count.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I qualified my answer as relating solely to BrE, because the Cambridge Dict. citation gives "[C]" alone for BrE, but "[C/U]" for AmE; whereas the Oxford Dict. has "Mass Noun" for BrE, & nothing for AmE. Can you throw any light on the difference?

Comment: Not on the peculiarities of dictionaries. 'Property' is count in 'We viewed three properties' and 'One unusual property of water is that the solid is less dense than the liquid around the freezing point.'  It is non-count in 'Property is theft' and 'This is the property of J Smith'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. In my last 2 paras., I acknowledged it can be count or mass for buildings & land; and count for 'attributes, etc.', which is consistent with what you've said. But the dictionaries seemed to suggest it could be non-count for possessions in AmE, which is what had me puzzled.