# When do I use a direct or indirect article to denote something?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, germanic-languages

The concrete example stems from a text that I am co-authoring with a friend whose native language is Czech. Mine is German. It goes like this:

> This regime is called random phase

To me, it feels like a direct article is missing. In English there's not much choice, so a "the" is missing before the "random phase". To him it seems superfluous or even false to include it. Another example is this one:

> We would like to know whether the system is in random phase or in ordered phase

Would one add the article here or not? I believe both options are possible, but I would have a slight tendency towards the inclusion of the article. Correct me if I'm wrong. I wonder also to which extend our native languages interfere. Slavic languages are not prone to inclusion of articles whereas Germanic languages are.

Comment: The first sentence in the Wikipedia article headed [Random phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_phase_approximation) is ***The** random phase approximation (RPA) is an approximation method in condensed matter physics and in nuclear physics.* If they use an article, I suggest you do the same. But this is a matter of domain-specific "jargon" - actual principles of English *grammar* have little if anything to say about your choice.

Comment: There ought not to be any article before the noun there. Else the meaning would change.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers. The example just happens to be from the field of physics, but the question is not related to jargon. Maybe it becomes clearer with these examples:
"This house is called (the) house of the rising sun." or "This man is called (the) terminator" or "This generation is called (the) generation X".

Comment: Thanks @Kris. Could you elaborate please on the way that the meaning changes.

Comment: Usage changes over time for specific contexts. Not many people today would talk about [***using the calculus***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=using+the+calculus%2Cusing+calculus&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cusing%20the%20calculus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cusing%20calculus%3B%2Cc0) to solve a mathematical problem - but according to that NGram, right up until the mid 60s it was actually more common to include the article than not.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As I noted a number of times on this site, nGrams can mislead into deceptive results. Never rely on nGrams without other corroborative evidence. "The want of a regular treatise, on the Calculus of Differences  ... translation of Lacroix's Differential and Integral Calculus, ..."; "more conformable to the principle and notation of the calculus of functions.". And don't even get me started on surgery: "The operation for extracting the calculus was appointed to be performed two days afterwards";

Comment: @Kris: It's true I included an NGram link in my comment, but I wasn't particularly thinking in terms of "corroborative evidence" when I wrote the first sentence. As much as anything else, it was just an easy way to colour-highlight ***using the calculus*** - a construction that I took it for granted almost all native speakers today would find at the very least "quaint".

Comment: ... Would you raise the same objections when I point out that **Google Books** has just a single instance of  *(someone) [**taught the calculus at**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22taught+the+calculus+at%22) (some educational establishment)*?  And that's a *very* odd one anyway - it's dated 1964, but the word "Calculus" is capitalised, and the vocabulary / style is reminiscent of the early Victorian era. Compare that to 417 hits for article-less [*taught calculus at*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22taught+calculus+at%22)

Comment: Questions about articles are often **unanswerable** without enough context. You have stated that this is for a "text." What kind of text? A headline text? A textbook? A research paper? A work of fiction? Second, trying to analyze or teach the use of articles in isolated sentences is problematic, since noun phrases (which articles are always part of) very often refer to things outside of the sentence in which they occur.  Third, choosing between a direct & indirect noun phrase is often a matter of style.  Both your sentences are grammatical, given the proper context and style.

Comment: Thanks. I feel misunderstood and treated unfairly.I asked for (a) short discussion of (the) grammatical and semantical implications of omitting (a) direct article in (the) sentences. As to (the) grammatical implications  there seems to be (a) consensus that both are correct.Regarding (the) meaning one comment states there oughtn't be any article,another says it depends on (the) historical context or yet other contexts.My examples aren't headline texts or poetry.The answer could be along (the) lines: The sentence in question requires the noun to be an established expression or specified earlier

Comment: If you want a simple answer as such, then consider [Q: Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) especially the answer by GoDucks. Else, papers, theses, books have been written about the articles in English and there is as yet no unifying theory that covers all cases, which is yet another reason there is no true simple explanation. As well, 95% of native speakers have no idea how to explain the use of articles in English.

Comment: What you have is one of almost no examples in the English language where it really doesn’t matter whether you use an article; at least, in the second case.

In every-day English, “This regime is called random phase” appears to cry out for an article, almost certainly “the” but it’s not truly necessary, as should be evident from the second example.

For future reference, all other things being equal, everyone should trust German before Czech ideas about English articles.

Comment: It might be helpful if you gave the whole paragraph(s) -- a bit more usage context -- rather than just the phrase. 
@Robbie Goodwin. Why do you think German ideas on the English article are more likely to be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of an article depends on the specific context—and what you intend the sentence to convey.

**Context #1: Words as Words**

> The word for that red fruit is *apple*.

Here, *apple* is not being used within the sentence functionally but as *a word*. You could describe it as playing a "meta" role within the sentence.

As described by *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed), 7.63:

> When a word or term is not used functionally but is referred to as the word or term itself, it is either italicized or enclosed in quotation marks.

Although that discusses how such words or terms should be styled, the discussion of its syntactical role is what's important here.

In contrast, neither of the following constructions would be correct:

> The word for that red fruit is an *apple*.
>   The word for that red fruit is *an apple*.

Because you are referring to *apple* as a word, putting an article in front of it is inappropriate. (And it is not the phrase *an apple* that is being discussed.)

Taking your example sentence and rephrasing it slightly, we can end up:

> The name of this regime is *random phase*.

Here, *random phase* is being used as *a phrase* just as *apple* was being used as *word*.

Further, neither of these analogous constructions would be correct:

> The name of this regime is a *random phase*.
>   The name of this regime is *a random phase*.

---

**Context #2: Words as Functional Components**

> I am holding an apple in my hand.

Unlike in the first context, *apple* is now serving a functional role within the sentence itself. As such, the article is appropriate.

Removing the article would result in a construction that was incorrect (assuming it's still the same single apple):

> I am holding apple in my hands.

Again, rephrasing your example sentence, we can end up with:

> This is a random phase.

Removing the article would result in something similarly incorrect:

> This is random phase.

---

**Disambiguation: Your Example Sentence**

Here is your actual example sentence:

> This regime is called random phase.

You need to ask yourself in what way you are *using* the phrase *random phase*. Is it being used as a phrase (Context #1) or is it being used as a functional component (Context #2)?

The problem is that your sentence construction isn't as explicit as the constructions I've been using. Therefore, *random phase* sometimes sounds correct with the article in front of it, and sometimes sounds correct without it.

While you *can* use what sounds right to you (the problem is that the two of you disagree on what that is), it's more logical to place it within the correct interpretation and then use the syntax that would be appropriate for that unambiguous interpretation.

**Context #1**:

> (This regime is called random phase.)
>   The name of this regime is *random phase*.
>   The term for this type of regime is *random phase*.
>   *Random phase* is what this regime is referred to as.

**Context #2**:

> (This regime is called random phase.)
>   This regime is a random phase.
>   This is a random-phase regime.
>   This is a random phase type of regime.

---

There is also nothing wrong with defining the term (or name) on its first use (Context #1), and then referring to it directly in subsequent uses just as you would any other noun.

Note that even though I used the indirect article in my examples, if *random phase* is a unique (or singular) item, then the direct article can be used. And if it is actually a proper noun, it's common (although not necessary) to capitalize it (as in *the Random Phase* or *The Random Phase*).

Comment: Do you mean (since you don't list it as a possibility) that *this regime is called the random phase* is ungrammatical? I don't agree at all. Would you say *this landmark is called Statue of Liberty*?

Comment: @PeterShor No, I don't mean that at all. It's perfectly grammatical. However, because of its specific wording (and styling), the original version can sound natural with an article or without an article. In a semantic analogy, it's somewhat similar to *They were cooking apples.* (What is the referent of *they*?)

Comment: I know something about statistical mechanics, and my guess is that by far the most natural wording for the OP's situation is *this regime is called the random phase*. Of course, it depends on the context, which they haven't told us enough about.

Comment: @PeterShor Right. We don't know enough about the context yet.

Comment: This is a very good answer but should rephrase one example or address that *I am holding apple in my hands* **isn't** ungrammatical when the referent is apple pulp or flavoring. Countable objects can be treated uncountably when they possess a particular substance/material/flavor/etc.

Comment: @lly I have clarified that bit for anybody whose thoughts stray to pulp. :)

Comment: Dear @JasonBassford. Thanks a lot for this well structured answer. It elucidates the two contexts and their possible disambiguations in my examples. I think in my case I am probably dealing with the first context. I will put the word in italic to emphasize that I'm defining a word, rather than describing the regime.

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence

> This regime is called random phase,

my intuition as a native speaker of English says that you need to have an article before "random".

You seem to be giving a name to a specific regime. Names like this (containing a countable common noun) usually have *the* in front of them: *the band gap, the ground state, the Chrysler Building, the Mississippi River, the Badlands, the Great Plains, the Special Theory of Relativity, the Gulf Stream*.

How many regimes in the phase diagram are there that you are calling a "random phase"? If there's only one, it should be "the random phase". If there's more than one, you may need to rewrite your sentence, because the sentence as written seems to imply that there is only one regime called a "random phase".

Similarly, for your second sentence, you should use "the ordered phase" or "an ordered phase" depending on whether there is one or more than one ordered phase.

Comment: Dear Peter Shor. Thanks for your answer and your intuition, especially coming from a physics/mathemaics/compsci background and of course being a native speaker. I share this intuition even though I am not a native speaker. Regarding the distinction put forth by @JasonBassford, why are band gaps, ground states and random phases not like apples or pears? Is it because apples or pears are not countable common nouns?

Comment: @Mario: I think it's because in materials, there's usually only one ground state and one band gap, and in phase diagrams (at least in my limited experience), there's usually only one region with random phase, and so on. If there's only one of something, English has a strong tendency to use *the*. If there's more than one random phase in your phase diagram, I woudn't use *the*.

Comment: Thanks. That makes it quite clear for me. On another note: I know it doesn't add to the discussion, but I am a great admirer of your work and very glad to receive an answer from you. I have also studied quantum algorithms briefly from the physics perspective under the supervision of Terry Rudolph, looking into decoherence issues. I was quite surprised to find that it was THE Peter Shor who replied to my question. In this case I'm confident about the placement of the direct article :)

Answer (score 0):

As a native English speaker, `This regime is called random phase` sounds weird to me. But `This phenomena is called random phase` sounds perfectly natural. Generally, if you are referring to something that only happens or exists once, the definite article sounds much more natural.

Consider the following two sentences:
`This event is called enlightenment` vs `This event is called the enlightenment.`

The first sentence sounds like it is referring to the Buddhist state of enlightenment - something which happens many times to many people. Whereas the second sounds like it is referring to a specific, singular historical time period.

A specific regime only occurs once, therefore I would say `This regime is called the Random Phase` sounds far more natural.