# Why the determiner "the" is missing?

Tags: grammar

"The descriptions given by people who claimed to have seen the puma were extraordinarily similar." It is a sentence from the first article of the NEW CONCEPT ENGLISH 3. I was wondering that why the determiner "the" is missing before "people" because my understanding was that people was specified to who claimed to have seen the puma.

Comment: It's a bare noun - just like the one you used in your own sentence in the snippet *missing before () "people"*.

Comment: Larry, the use of determiners is difficult for people learning English; native speakers don't think about it and don't need to learn rules.  There's nothing wrong with the rule you cite, it's just that it has limited application--a first approximation.  You will notice many examples of bare nouns as you read.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a.  The answers there go into detail--so this is really a duplicate.

Comment: @Xanne No, those answers do not address this question.

Comment: @Lawrence But that's a citation of *people*, a mention, not a use.

Comment: @Araucaria It's a mention, but the mention still counts as a noun.

Comment: Larry, it's similar to this: *Dogs who work with police departments must receive special training.*  We omit the definite article if we want to speak in generalities.  Here's another: *Articles are omitted when speaking in generalities.*