# Could somebody please help me out with articles?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Being Russian, I am having a fairly hard time understanding the concept of articles usage in various situations. Also it is hard to find truly elaborate manuals online. So here I would like to give an example that I find unclear.

1)  In fact, in one zoo, questions of animal safety arose when two red pandas were found dead after being exposed to rat poison. (Why is there no article required here before "rat poison"? Is it because the poison is an uncountable noun?)

2)  Let's talk about spoilers: why 'spoiler culture' is demeaning to the real power and beauty of film. (Why is there an article before "real power" here? I would assume that the word power is also uncountable)

Thank you!

Comment: I think [GoDuck's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/298746/18696) at the linked question is probably the most helpful. A *specific* power will have the definite article; a *generic* batch of poison won't.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the bit at the end of GoDuck's answer, where *the experience I had at work today* is said to be an exception to the general rule. In this post, it's the *of film* that forces the *the*. If you could be demeaning to power and beauty as abstract concepts, you would be able to say *demeaning to power and beauty*, without the *the*.