# The usage of articles in IELTS Task 1 (writing)

Tags: articles, ielts

I am practicing the first writing task in IELTS. My concern is specifically related to the usage of the article "the" while writing about pie charts. Should I use this article every time I mention the name of a specific portion of the pie or should I stop after the first mention? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The definite article is not one of the words that can or must be omitted in each subsequent mention of the noun. But I suggest you edit your answer to include a chunk of text exemplifying your problem.

Comment: In English (apart from headline writing), every noun requires some sort of determiner or article -- which can include the zero article. Note that it's not a question of omitting an article; if a zero article is appropriate, it's a zero article. We already have a [question on articles with good answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a).