# How to understand which nouns are specific and which ones aren't

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

This is how most people would explain it:

- **I want to buy a new car.** You want to buy some car. You don't know which one exactly, Toyota or BMW, which color, and so on.
- **The car parked near the baker's shop is red.** Specific car. That one car.
- **Hey, Joe. You know, I bought a new car yesterday.** I bought some car.

As I know, the third example is correct (as well as the 1st and 2nd ones), but it confuses me. When I buy a car, I buy the specific one. For example, it could have a small scratch on its door.

Why we use the indefinite article there?

Comment: I bought a new car yesterday. The car is red. A=one.

Comment: It's whether it's contextually specific (already mentioned, or demanded by logic).

Comment: You would only say "Hey, Joe, I bought the new car yesterday" if Joe already knew that you had had your eye on a particular car.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, I know, thank you for pointing it out. The problem is that I don't understand the logic behind the 3rd example. I cannot distinguish it from the logic of the second one, and consequently make a lot of grammatical errors.

Comment: That's what I was trying to clarify. If Joe had _not_ known that you were planning to buy a car, you say 'a car' because that is the first he has heard of it; it's an anonymous car _to him_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry, it doesn't. I like [Ash's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/202579/273573), but none of the answers provided there answers my question. That is, how to make the distinction between 2nd and 3rd case clear.

Comment: @johnc.j. The question is the same, and the answer is the same—as also pointed out in comments here. If Joe is unaware of the fact that you've bought a car, then **the** would be incoherent in that construction. Even if you were pointing at your new car, you wouldn't use *the*, you'd use *this*. You have to establish a specific reference before you can use *the*. That reference can follow in words immediately after, but that's not the case here. However, you could say this: "Hey, Joe. Look at ***the*** *new car I bought yesterday*," which matches the construction of the second sentence.