# Why is 'the' usage is incorrect in the sentence below?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

We enjoy **the** life on this planet because of diversity.

why article 'the' is incorrect when used with 'life' ?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Whether it is incorrect or not depends on what meaning you intend to give to the word *life.* We have [another similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) with quite a number of answers which provide information on articles. If that doesn't help, please [edit this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/544083/edit) to explain why.

Comment: It's not incorrect. Where do you get the idea that it is?

Comment: It is not incorrect. "The life" adds little or nothing to "Life" but the meaning is still is clear and unambiguous.