# Do names take an article?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Do I need to use the definite article *the* in this case?

> - Copycats are Google's enemies.
> - Copycats are **the** Google's enemies.

There is no context, just a statement (these enemies aren't identified).

Comment: Google is a proper noun (note its capitalization) and therefore does not require an article. You wouldn't say, "I am going to the Paris, which is in the France".

Comment: Well, if I replace Google with, say, 'brand's' (some imaginary brand), does your answer still apply?

Comment: @Micah Windsor But The Hague is in the Netherlands. _Google_ is an anarthrous proper noun.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I could argue that 'The Hague' is an anarthrous proper noun (as a phrase), while 'Hague' on its own is meaningless in English.

Comment: @Micah Windsor But you're still left with [_the_ Netherlands]. '_Google_ is a proper noun (note its capitalization) and therefore does not require an article' is infelicitous. Note also 'ITV's most watched programmes' _**but**_ 'the BBC's most watched programmes'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Rats, you've got me there :)

Comment: So, is it better to say 'X are brand's enemies'? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you replace 'brand' with any actual brand name.

Answer (score 2):

General rule: **Names do not take an article.**

As stated in comments, English does not have sentences like "I am going to the Paris, which is in the France."

Confusingly, *some* names actually include an article, but these are special cases — and even then the article might actually be a determiner as in "the Thames": there, we are distinguishing a particular river from the set of all rivers. Where a name really includes an article, the article is usually capitalised as well, like "The Times" which is a newspaper published in London. (Not the London.) Because they are special cases, it's safe to use a general rule and either learn special cases separately, or not treat them as special at all. "The Times" could be referring to the "Times" newspaper, after all — one of many, again.

The Dutch city *The Hague* does have an article; it's part of the name and always capitalised, but it's a direct translation from *Den Haag* and one of the special cases to be learned.

Related question: [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) although answers there don't mention names.