# Article after higher / high + noun

Tags: articles

I know that there are similar questions here, but I still don't understand everything.
I wrote 4 almost identical sentences below with a place for an article marked as "...". Please tell me what are correct articles here. I know that these sentences can be rewritten without articles and with keeping the same sense, but I am interested in these particular examples. It is not a homework or something like that by the way.

We must keep it at ... higher angle.

We must keep it at ... high angle.

You must drive at ... high speed.

You must drive at ... higher speed.

Comment: (1) a; mandatory // (2) a; mandatory // (3) a is possible but the zero article is normally more idiomatic (or indeed 'fast/er') // (4) a is normally preferable to the zero article here, but both are far less natural-sounding than 'faster'.

Comment: @Edwin: I was about to disagree with you, but then I realized that you meant *faster* rather than *a faster speed*. So this comment is just to keep other people from similarly misinterpreting your comment.

Comment: @Peter Yes; 'You must drive at higher speed' (rarefied) // 'You must drive at a higher speed' (very formal) // 'You must drive faster' (what almost everyone would say). //// There are so many questions on articles that I feel sure this is a repeat, but I'm not going to spend hours looking. But I don't think it warrants an 'answer' answer.

Comment: Our canonical question is [Q2031](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2031). Learning articles can be difficult for those whose native language doesn't use them in the same way: I would suggest that [ell.se] might be a better place for this sort of question if the answers at the above link don't help.