# "With probability", "with a probability", "with the probability"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles, mathematics

As a mathematician, I often write and read about probabilities. In the literature, I've seen versions of all the sentences below. Which one is correct?

> This happens with probability (of) 30%.

> This happens with the probability (of) 30%.

> This happens with a probability (of) 30%.

In particular, what article should one use and is "of" correct/necessary?

Comment: When I hear a weather report, it's of the form *The chance of rain is 30%.*  When I read a math / statistics paper, I have seen *With probability 0.30* and *With a probability p=0.30* or *With a p-value = 0.0235*. I have rarely seen the definite article, e.g., *With the probability of 0.30* simply because mathematicians rarely talk about 30% as the "one-and-only" 30%. .

Comment: **English** usage is at [our question about articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a). This appears to be jargon, though: a field-specific usage for mathematical academic literature.

Comment: [Here's an NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+probability+25%2Cwith+a+probability+25%2Cwith+a+probability+of+25%2Cwith+the+probability+25%2Cwith+the+probability+of+25&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwith%20probability%2025%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20a%20probability%20of%2025%3B%2Cc0) querying all relevant permutations. Showing that *with a probability of 25%* beats out article-less *with probability 25%* - the others *(with a probability 25% with the probability 25%, with the probability of 25%)* are all just too rare to chart.

Comment: Agree with the comments above.  Would add that when you give the shorter version ("The event occurs with probability 30%") you get a marginally more scientific/technical sound than when you use "a... of" (to my ears at least).

Comment: with a probability of 30% OR with  30% probability.

Answer (score -1):

Dear fellow mathematician!

Here is a math question:
Output and interpret the prediction interval for the one-step forecast of your chosen model.

I answered:
hilo(fc) %>% select(Date, '80%')
With probability 80%, the one-step future value will fall in that prediction interval.

I got points deducted and the feedback from Prof. Edwards:
'''
You can't say "with probability" when interpreting a confidence interval or prediction interval.  You can only say that if you are doing a Bayesian analysis.
'''

I had learnt game theory as an economic student where the phrase "w.p." had been used all the time and was not most familiar with that rigorous math terminology when I recently made a mistake in a math course.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a different issue, Dorian: 'Is the term "probability" correct in this context?' OP asks about which article to use, and whether to include 'of'. Yours is a maths/stats or even philosophy question. Of course, 'probability' needs to be rigorously defined locally before one can even start an analysis. Better asked on Mathematics.SE.

Comment: As people have answered "With probability 0.30" and "With a probability p=0.30" are acceptable -use no article or indefinite article, I just want to in addition emphasis the correct use of the phrase "with probability". If the context of "probability" is frequentist instead, expressions like 30% of the times should be correct.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that:

> This happens with probability 30%

Here adding 'of' would be ungrammatical. Whilst

> This happens with a probability of 30%

Here the 'of' is necessary for the sentence to be gramatically correct.

Comment: Hello, Mozibur.  While I agree that these sound the most natural (and my degrees are in science, and I taught maths/statistics), ELU expects answers to be backed by linked and attributed supporting references. // I'm not sure that this warrants the downvote, though. It would often be better if downvotes required reasons to be added.