# Complete the article. Use a, the or no article (-)

Tags: grammar, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Would you like to explain the answer no.11?
I think No.11 need filling with "the" article, because it is the typical music. But the key is no article. I am confused

> (s)............ name of the band was changed to The Beatles and it became one of (9)............ most commercially successful and critically acclaimed acts in (10)............ history of (11)..............popular music. They built their reputation playing clubs in (12)............ Liverpool and (13)..............Hamburg
> in (14)............ Germany over a three-year period from 1960.

Comment: It's only possible to link to the question, but one of the answers is [the best answer for **this** question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/202579/18696). "The zero article is used for a category" [like "popular music"].

Comment: Switching the category, ' ... in the history of the opera' would refer to (the history of) one particular opera, say _Il Trovatore_. We need ' ... in the history of opera' to refer to an overview of opera.