# Article after 'added' or 'implemented' in software changelogs

Tags: articles, attributive-nouns

I'm writing a document describing what has been added or changed in a new version of a software app. Among the changes are new features allowing the users to do certain things.

(1) Is it correct to say "Implemented an option allowing..." or should it be "Implemented the option allowing..."? (2) Is it better to say "Added a 'XXX' section where you can see..." or should it be "Added the 'XXX' section where you can..."?

Note: The features listed in the changelogs haven’t been mentioned somewhere before by app's developers

Comment: Both are grammatical. Use whichever makes more sense at the time.

Comment: I would say it depended on the context 'an option' would be used if the author had agency over which change to implement. 'the option' would be more appropriate if the authour was reporting the completion of a task they had been told to complete.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: This question is not opinion based. Please stop using 'opinion based' close reasons for questions that simply have more than one answer. If the answer is "It depends", give the conditions on which it depends.

Answer (score 1):

Request: we need a button to easily download all the data from the app.

Changelog, after the implementation:

1. **Added a button to download all the data.** This simply means that a new feature was added.
2. **Added the button to download all the data.** This means that a specific new feature was added, and the reader should probably be aware of this specific feature: maybe it was a popular request, maybe it was a very noticeable bug, maybe the button plays an important role in the interface, etc.
3. **Added button to download data.** This is the short form (no articles), common in titles, comments, notes, and therefore in changelogs as well.