# Should this use of "the" be "a" instead?

Tags: grammar

> It was an odd message for a spam text, and there was no further explanation, only the participation inquiry.

I feel like it should be rephrased to:

> It was an odd message for a spam text, and there was no further explanation, **there was only a participation inquiry.**

By the way, the text is:

> If you climb to the edge of the obelisk, your wish will be granted. Would you like to participate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Answer (score 0):

> It was an odd message for a spam text, and there was no further explanation, only the participation inquiry.

**The** is correct. **The** requires that its noun is known by both speaker and audience.  Depending on where the actual text is, it is to be understood as

1. [where the explanation/definition of the noun follows the use of "**the** noun"]: It was an odd message for a spam text, and there was no further explanation, only **the** participation inquiry **that I will now give to you:**"If you climb to the edge of the obelisk, your wish will be granted. Would you like to participate?"

or the explanation/definition can **precede** the use of "the" (this is commonest)

2. The text said: "that I will now give to you:"If you climb to the edge of the obelisk, your wish will be granted. Would you like to participate?" It was an odd message for a spam text, and there was no further explanation, only the participation inquiry.

**The** noun = "**that** noun **of which you are, or will become, aware**."