# When talking about school kids, can we say 'the' kids, or is the article superfluous?

Tags: articles

A Russian colleague has insisted my use of an article in a review is incorrect. I feel although it may be superfluous, it isn't incorrect. The sentence reads:

> I believe that progressive learning of English is possible through fun interactions with *the* kids, but I never forget about discipline.

Is the use of *the* before 'kids' incorrect? Or simply old fashioned/unnecessary?

Comment: AFAIK, Russian Language speakers do not use articles, so I would take what your friend says with a grain of _соль_ That said, all of this would depend on the context, as the definite article _the_ refers to specific kids or groups, and the zero article would refers to ALL kids.

Comment: Context is an issue- have you mentioned kids previously in this text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: As the other commenters say, context is key, and 'I believe that progressive learning of English is possible through fun interactions with the kids, but I never forget about discipline.' is unlikely to be the first sentence. 'The' would be licensed, mandatory in fact, if one intended this to mean 'one's own kids' (unlikely here), and available if one had already mentioned teaching children English. And in fact the 'I never forget about discipline' post-defines the children involved, making the use of the article probably the better choice..

Comment: The clause "_but I never forget about discipline_" implies that you are referring to the kids you teach in your classroom. If this is the case, then the definite article is in my opinion the better choice. It is certainly not incorrect. This has nothing to do with whether or not the usage is old-fashioned.

Comment: "The kids" can mean "young people in general" as in such pop/rock songs as "Doing it for the kids", "The kids are alright", "If the kids are united", etc, but this use is colloquial/slangy. Arguably kids meaning children is always slangy/colloquial, but it's less so than it once was.

Comment: In your example, I would read "the kids" as referring to the kids in a particular classroom. It sounds logical to me, even if you never specifically opened the topic of kids before in this conversation. I think most people can already infer from the topic being discussed (teaching) that there will be kids in a classroom, and that when you say "the kids" that you're talking about those kids, and not some other kids (e.g. not your own kids at home, if you have kids at home as well).

Comment: Are you talking about the kids you teach specifically? Then, it can be the kids. OR: Is it a general statement? If so, no the. Believe me, I did an entire course on the use of this determiner in the legal field in English. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that progressive learning of English is possible through fun interactions with **the** kids, but I never forget about discipline.

The definite article is only licensed if the noun is known to the speaker and listener. This can be done by

(1) general knowledge "The Moon is bright" - we are all aware of the Moon.

(2) previous reference (I saw a boy. The boy was tall) or postpositional reference "The boy was tall. Apparently, he was the son of the blacksmith."

**The** directs the listner's/reader's attention to a specific noun: one that is described or defined.

Without "the", "kids" = kids in general.

In your example, "**the** kids" indicate a specified group and the nature of that group **must** be known to both the writer and reader/listener.

In your example, you have not described any group, so "the" is wrong. Your audience would ask "Which kids?".

*It may be that you have mentioned and defined/specified this group of kids in an earlier part of the speech/article if so then "**the**" would be appropriate.*

Answer (score 0):

It's correct to include the definite article if the speaker is talking about their experience teaching English as a second language to children.

But if we give weight to the intro "I believe," then the statement becomes more about the speaker's teaching philosophy, which is general and rather abstract, and therefore omitting the definite article would be best.

I imagine that your Russian colleague has spent considerable effort trying to get articles right, as this is a major challenge for Russian speakers.  It's good that this person has given articles so much thought.

Comment: That a Russian speaker *may* or may not have spent considerable time and thought to the usage of articles in English does not mean their correction is valid.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - No.  Agreed.  I was just suggesting a diplomatic way that OP might discuss the difference of opinion with the colleague.

Comment: We're not about [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Mari-LouA - It wasn't intended as the main point of my post.  It was meant to be the icing on the cake.  OP can take it or leave it.

Comment: Referring to "I believe" I would say that it does make the statement more about the speaker's teaching philosophy but if the speaker is expressing a philosophy relating to classroom teaching then "the kids" is still correct as they are talking about "the kids in a class" even though "a class" is abstract. I also think that the vast majority of native speakers would use the definite article in this and similar cases, particularly if they were being sufficienly informal as to use "kids" rather than "children".

Comment: @BoldBen - My mind's ear can hear it either way.

Comment: I'd agree, Neither of them sounds 'wrong' to me, there are just, as usual, slight differences in emphasis. I suspect that this flexibility sometimes causes problems for ESOL students, particularly if their native language is very strictly defined. I know virtually nothing about Russian but suspect that it might be one of those tightly defined languages. If our countries and cultures were not so closely associated I suspect that French speakers would be confused by the flexibility because of the influence of the Academe Francaise.

Comment: @BoldBen - You won't find me criticizing that academy because whenever I read translations to multiple European languages, the French version is always impeccable while some of the others are often a sloppy mess.

Comment: @aparente001 I wasn't criticising, just using it as an example of a language with strict formal definition.

Comment: @BoldBen - Ah..

Answer (score 0):

'The' used in the sentence is incorrect.

the kids- You have mentioned them before. They are already known to us.

Kids- kids in general, all kids in the world

the kids- a particular group of kids

We do not use 'the' with a general meaning. We use 'the' with a specific meaning.

Comment: This answer is too general (although it is correct for this case): "The tiger is a dangerous animal," is a perfectly good English sentence, and means all tigers are dangerous.

Comment: Peter Shor, I wanted to answer the specific question. Of course,// "The tiger is a dangerous animal," is a perfectly good English sentence, and means all tigers are dangerous.// 'The dog is a faithful animal' means all dogs are faithful. (The dog=dogs in general, all dogs in the world). Thanks for contribution to my answer.